# Eclipse Java Maven project disable dafault project facets

Tags: java, spring, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Using Eclipse Luna SR1 with the m2e plugin, I have created a Java web project with Maven.

How do I remove the default project facets (e.g. CDI, JPA, etc.) in the project's pom.xml?

[image]

*Unchecking "Project Facets" in Project -> Properties resets after Maven -> Update Project.*

Comment: Cleaned up grammar..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either disable the m2e integration with the related Facets at the workspace preferences or the project properties level, under Maven > Java EE integration (for JAX-RS, JPA, JSF) and under JBoss Tools > JBoss Maven Integration for CDI, Hibernate, ...

Alternatively, you can use pom properties directly in your pom.xml :

```
 <m2e.jaxrs.activation>false</m2e.jaxrs.activation>
 <m2e.jpa.activation>false</m2e.jpa.activation>
 <m2e.jsf.activation>false</m2e.jsf.activation>
 <m2e.cdi.activation>true</m2e.cdi.activation>
```

For more information, please refer to :

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/1.0.0#Enable.2FDisable_the_JAX-RS.2FJPA.2FJSF_Configurators_at_the_pom.xml_level
- http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.2.0.Final.html#pom-properties-controlled-project-configurators

Please note that the JAX-WS Node you see in the project explorer is automatically added by WTP and is not controlled by any m2e integration plugin.

If it bothers you, you can hide it from the Project Explorer view,  Customize View...>Content> uncheck JAX-WS Web Services Elements

Comment: Can u direct me to disabling org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature as well?

Comment: The Javascript Facet is automatically added along the Web Facet (with current versions on Eclipse, that might change in the future).

the only way to disable automatic Javascript enablement is to disable m2e-wtp integration completely : < m2e.wtp.activation >false< m2e.wtp.activation > (see https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP/New_and_Noteworthy/1.1.0)